# Car HUD and android bluetooth communication

Tags: android, xamarin.android, hud

I currently have a streaming internet radio app that runs on android.  I am wanting to have it communicate with Car HUDs so I can display the current song info on the HUD screen.

For example, I just bought a new Honda Pilot.  I noticed that when I use a CD , it displays the song info.  If I run off of a USB device (for example, an ipod), it will display the song info. However, if I run off of a bluetooth it will show blank for artist, song, etc., but it will show that the bluetooth is running through the phone and displays "Droid Razr".

This got me thinking, what if I manually send the music info to the HUD from the phone, every time the song changes.

My question is, can this be done?  Do I need some kind of API to do this?  If so, which one?  And does said API work with Mono Android?

Answer (score 1):

When you say HUD, you probably mean the cluster display (A real HUD is projected or rendered on the windshield). In any case, the bluetooth profile that transfers track information is [AVRCP 1.3+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29). If either your head unit or your phone doesn't support this version of the profile, you will be unable to see the track information. CD track info is a [different protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_Description_Protocol) altogether and only depends on the tie-up between your cluster controller and CD player.

If you are able to determine that your car's head unit/bluetooth controller does support AVRCP 1.3 and you have an android phone - you may be able to experiment with flashing custom ROMS (try [xda-developers](http://www.xda-developers.com) for your device) that support AVRCP 1.3 and see if metadata is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Gotcha on the HUD.  Looked up cluster display and I am not sure if that's what it is either (could be though).  But it's the display where they show the song info.  Ha!! my terminology stinks!! But I will look into what you posted.  Thanks